# Can't reach docker-hosted SQL server from web app docker on same host

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

On the same virutal machine (remote, ubuntu), I have

- **An SQL Server** running in a Docker
- **An .NET Core 2.2** (IdentityServer) application running in a docker
- **An instance of [jwilder.nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)** serving as a reverse-proxy for every web application on the machine
- A multitude of other .NET Core apps

I am able to connect to all of my websites using both machine IP + port and domain name, which means the reverse proxy works as expected and the dockers are well-configured

**I am able to connect** to the SQL Server **using SSMS** from my local machine, which means that the SQL Server docker properly forwards the TCP connection on port 1433

The IdentityServer .NET Core 2 web application **is able to connect** to the SQL Server **when run on my local machine**.

**The remote-docker IdentityServer application can't reach the SQL Server instance** with the following error (shortened for clarity - removed stack trace)

> `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)`:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> (provider: `TCP Provider, error: 40` - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) at [...]

I know that the SQL server is running and reachable from the internet, and I know that the application's code is not at fault because I tested both.

So I deduced it had to be the IdentityServer docker that was blocking the connexion. So I tried:

- Using the `--expose 20` command on the IdentityServer docker
- Opening mapping the port 20 inside the container to some port outside `-p 45264:20` in addition to the already exposed port 80
- I originally worked on using the port 1433 on both sides of the mapping but since it didn't work I tried using an other port on the outside (20). Didn't change anything

Here is the connexion string used by the IdentityServer (sensitive data hidden):

```
Data Source=***.***.***.***,20;Initial Catalog=Identity;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Password=******************
```

Why can't my IdentityServer docker reach the SQL Server docker while the SQL Server itself is perfectly reachable? How can I make this setup work?

Comment: I couldn't decide if this was to be posted on StackOverflow or on ServerFault. Please flag & move if appropriate

Comment: So where are your connection parameters?

Comment: You mean you want me to post my connexion string?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: I added it. I'm posting it again in the comment so that you don't need to search through my OP `Data Source=***.***.***.***,20;Initial Catalog=Identity;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Password=******************`

Comment: This connexion string works perfecly when i'm reaching the SQL server from my local machine using the IdentityServer application BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up giving up on getting this to work using a single host, so I simply decided to have the SQL Server run in a separate machine.

Answer (score 1):

When wrapping SQL server into Docker, the first thing to anticipate is the way you connect. SQL Server prefers named pipes and you have to explicitly set mode to `tcp`.

If connection is done locally, don't use `localhost`, change it to `127.0.0.1`. Also writing explicit `tcp:` prefix may help, like this: `Server=tcp:x.y.z.q,1433`

Comment: I have changed my connexion string to use `Server=tcp:127.0.0.1,20` but the same error still occurs. I tried specifying the `tpc:` when using the public IP in the connexion string too, didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you run Sql Server and IdentityServer (which has connection problem) in separate docker containers.

If this is so then referring to localhost (i.e. 127.0.0.1) is not correct. Because in this case IdentityServer tries to connect to itself. This would work if the IdentityServer have run on the host machine, since you forward SQL server port to it. But in your case, you should connect to the SQL server container IP instead.
Considering all above I see three options for you to solve this:

1. You can get ip address of SQL Server container by running `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <sql_container_name_or_id>`
2. Run SQL container with static IP via `docker run --ip <static_ip_value> <sql_container_name_or_id>` and then use static ip you have specified in connection string.
3. Run SQL container with specified host name via `docker run --hostname <sql_host_name> <sql_container_name_or_id>` and then use specified hostname in the connection string.

It is up to you which way to go.

Comment: There are some other options if you want to use docker swarm, to configure it via compose yml, but as far as I understood you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use tcp, 127.0.0.1 and host port to connect. Mention in the identity server docker settings that it depends on sql database server container. Like this,

```
identityservice:
   ...
   depends_on:
      - sqldataservice
```

This way the database container will be made available first.

```
"ConnectionString": "Server=tcp:127.0.0.1,8433;Database=dbname;User Id=sa;Password=abc@1234;"
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Mention in the identity server docker settings that it depends on sql database server container"? I'm sorry I'm kinda new to docker I don't understand what you mean. I tried using `--expose 20` on the IdentityServer docker if that's what you mean

Comment: inside the docker compose yml file where you defined identity server service, write depends_on: after the sql database service name.

Comment: I don't use docker compose. My startup script is based on the `docker run [...]` command. I'll lookup how to use "depends_on" without compose.

Comment: Okay, check on that. If you do not use docker compose then, you just have to make sure sql db container is running prior to running idp server